# How to use RX to control command's availability in complex scenarios?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, system.reactive

### The setup

Let's assume the following. We have a following **theoretical** viewmodel class for WPF application:

```cs
public MyViewModel
{

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // Condition under which this command may be executed is:
        // this.ActiveDocument.Highlighting.Type == Highlighting.Xml && 
        //    !this.ActiveDocument.IsReadOnly && 
        //    (this.License.Kind == LicenseKind.Full || this.License.TrialDay < 30)
        MyCommand = new Command(obj => DoSomething());
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; } 
    // (all other required properties)
}
```

In addition:

- Current class implements properly `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- All classes in member access chains implements properly `INotifyPropertyChanged` (eg. document viewmodel accessible from `ActiveDocument` property)
- `ActiveDocument` may be `null`. `ActiveDocument.Highlighting` may also be null.

### The problem

I'd like the command to be enabled only when the condition in comment is met.

### Option without RX

I wrote [my own library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spooksoft.VisualStateManager/) for handling such situations. The solution would be either:

```cs
public MyViewModel
{
    private readonly Condition commandAvailableCondition;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        commandAvailableCondition = new LambdaCondition(this, 
            vm => m.ActiveDocument.Highlighting.Type == Highlighting.Xml && 
                !vm.ActiveDocument.IsReadOnly && 
                (vm.License.Kind == LicenseKind.Full || vm.License.TrialDay < 30),
            false);

        MyCommand = new AppCommand(obj => DoSomething(), commandAvailableCondition);
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; } 
    // (all other required properties)
}
```

Or - if you want the code be a little bit more readable, so that partial conditions could be reused - like that:

```cs
public MyViewModel
{
    private readonly Condition commandAvailableCondition;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        var highlightingIsXml = new LambdaCondition(this, 
            vm => vm.ActiveDocument.Highlighting.Type == Highlighting.Xml, 
            false);
        var documentIsReadonly = new LambdaCondition(this,
            vm => vm.ActiveDocument.IsReadOnly, 
            false);
        var appIsLicensed = new LambdaCondition(this,
            vm => vm.License.Kind == LicenseKind.Full || this.License.TrialDay < 30,
            false);

        commandAvailableCondition = highlightingIsXml & !documentIsReadonly & appIsLicensed;

        MyCommand = new AppCommand(obj => DoSomething(), commandAvailableCondition);
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; } 
    // (all other required properties)
}
```

What my library (or, more precisely, `LambdaCondition` class) does is:

- It keeps track of all instances implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and handle changes (eg. when `ActiveDocument` changes or `ActiveDocument.Highlighting` changes or `ActiveDocument.Highlighting.Type` changes etc.)
- It keeps track of possible `null`s on the way in which case it will return default value (in this case, `false`)
- It will automatically reports changes (but only changes) of availability to the command, so that UI may be refreshed when needed.

### The question

How one would implement the scenario described above using `System.Reactive` in C#? Is it possible to do it easily while keeping all requirements about `INotifyPropertyChanged`, nulls on the way and the default value? You may make any sane assumptions when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The [ReactiveUI](https://www.reactiveui.net/) framework has a `ReactiveCommand` class that uses an `IObservable<T>` to refresh the status of the command (i.e. raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the `ICommand`).

Please refer to the [docs](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/#controlling-executability) for an example of how use it to control executability:

```
var canExecute = this.WhenAnyValue(
    x => x.UserName, x => x.Password,
    (userName, password) => 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password));

var command = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(LogOnAsync, canExecute);
```

Comment: Does it follow INotifyPropertyChange implementers in the property access chain? Does it also work properly if any of properties is null? Could you please show, how my specific example would look when implemented in RX?

Comment: `WhenAnyValue` does emit a new value when any of the `Username` and `Password` properties rasises the `PropertyChanged` event. What is your specific example exactly? What did you try?

Comment: Did you read my whole question? I've presented the exact condition, which is supposed to be watched: `vm => m.ActiveDocument.Highlighting.Type == Highlighting.Xml && !vm.ActiveDocument.IsReadOnly && (vm.License.Kind == LicenseKind.Full || vm.License.TrialDay < 30),` What if eg. `ActiveDocument` is null? Will RX handle it properly? I expect in this case the condition to have its default value (or at least false by default)

Comment: If `ActiveDocument`, you will get a `NullReferenceException`. This has nothing to do with RX.

Comment: In my library I won't. That's, among others, is why I'm interested, whether RX is well-suited for this task.